# Scripted manipulation of SSH public keys in the authorized_keys file

Tags: shell-script, ssh, text-processing, ssh-config

The `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file format can be briefly summarised as

- a text file with one line per key;
- empty lines and lines beginning with the octothorpe (`#`) are ignored;
- there are four fields: *options*, *keytype*, *key* and *comment*;
- fields one and four are optional;
- field one may contain whitespace if double-quoted;
- field four may contain whitespace without being quoted.

The full description is in `man sshd`.

**Is there a reliable, scriptable (e.g. `bash`), way to manipulate keys in the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file ?**

For example, a script might:

- extract a specific key (being the *keytype*, *key* and *comment* fields),
- manipulate (add, modify or remove) the *options* field,
- manipulate (add, modify or remove) the *comment* field,
- iterate over all keys, or
- remove a key.

There does not appear to be a SSH tool (e.g. `ssh-keygen`, `ssh-add` &c.) capable of modifying the `~/.ssh.authorized_keys` file, and the nature of the *options* and *comment* fields make this very difficult to reliably achieve using the usual `sed`, `awk` or `perl -pe` approach.

---

**Following comments**, here is a simplified problem: imagine a script that reads the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file and outputs all keys - only the keys: no options and no blank or comment lines.

I struggled to do this because each row is space-delimited but:

- the options can contain whitespace or be absent altogether, and
- the comments, due to whitespace, can be zero or more fields.

Therefore you have no idea how many fields that a row contains, and you can't easily tell how many of those fields the *options* spans.

You'd need a overly-complex regex that understands the scope of the *options* field so that it could remove it reliably before outputting the rest of the line. I tried to do this with `sed` and `perl -pe`.

A contrived use-case for such a script would be to [list the fingerprints of all keys](https://serverfault.com/questions/413231).

Comment: Given a key, you can add or remove comments to it, change its password, etc. with `ssh-keygen`. Beyond that, what you're asking doesn't make much sense. Let's say you have two keys with no comments, `ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1y...` and `ssh-rsa AAAAB3Nw3N2y...`. How can you tell which one you want to extract / modify / remove?

Comment: Well you would have to refer to it somehow, perhaps by supplying it, or its fingerprint, or its *bubblebabble* text, etc. If the whole gamut of the question doesn't make sense, then consider the simpler scenario of extracting or iterating over all keys ignoring any options field.

Comment: It's still not clear what would be the input, and what would be the output of such operation. _shrug_

Comment: Ok, *really simplify it*... imagine a script that lists the keys without any options field. I tried with `sed` and `perl -pe` but it's hard to do it reliably when you consider how flexible the specification of *options* and *comment* is.

Comment: I've added a simplified problem to the end of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description you seem to want to kill options and comment lines.  According to `man 8 sshd`:

> Public keys consist of the following space-separated fields: options, keytype, base64-encoded key, comment.  The options field is optional.  The keytype is “ecdsa-sha2-nistp256”, “ecdsa-sha2-nistp384”, “ecdsa-sha2-nistp521”, “ssh-ed25519”, “ssh-dss” or “ssh-rsa”; the comment field is not used for anything (but may be convenient for the user to identify the key).

Consequently you could do something like this:

```
sed '
    /^[ ]*$/d;
    /^#/d;
    s/^.* \(ecdsa-sha2-nistp256\|ecdsa-sha2-nistp384\|ecdsa-sha2-nistp521\|ssh-ed25519\|ssh-dss\|ssh-rsa\) /\1 /' \
        ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

This assumes key comments don't contain `ssh-dss`, `ssh-rsa`, etc.  It also assumes a `sed(1)` implementation that supports `OR` (i.e. `\|`).

Using a text editor might prove both easier and safer. :)

Comment: That's qualifies as the nasty regex to which I alluded, but thanks - that's better than what I had. I had hoped for some utility that I hadn't heard of :)